# Como crear una variable de sesión en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy haciendo una comprobación del ancho de pantalla en la página de inicio y estoy creando una variable de sesión de la siguiente forma:

```
if(!isset($_GET['Ancho']) && !isset($_GET['Alto'])){
    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">
    <!-- 
    document.location=\"$PHP_SELF?Ancho=\"+screen.width+\"&Alto=\"+screen.height;
    //-->
    </script>";
} else {
    if(isset($_GET['Ancho']) && isset($_GET['Alto'])) {
        // Resolución de pantalla detectada
        // echo "Esta es tu resolucion de pantalla: Ancho= ".$_GET['Ancho']." y Alto= ".$_GET['Alto'];
        $_SESSION["anchoPantalla"] = $_GET['Ancho'];
        $_SESSION["altoPantalla"] = $_GET['Alto'];
    } else {
        // error en la detección de resolución de pantalla
        // echo "No se ha podido detectar la resolución de pantalla";
    }
}
```

Noté que al hacer esto en el index.php me deja la direccion como:

```
index.php?Ancho=1366&Alto=768
```

El problema que tengo es que la variable de sesion que defino como $_SESSION["anchoPantalla"] no lo reconoce en toda la aplicación...

**Pregunta 1:** Cómo puedo hacer para que me tome esa variable de sesion ?
**Pregunta 2:** Como puedo hacer para evitar que se muestre esos valores en el index.php ?

Comment: Con mi poco conocimiento lo primero que te voy a decir es que nunca abres la sesion. Es decir estas llamando/creando variables de session sin ninguna creada. Para crearla escribe en tu código antes de las variables session_start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que puedas usar tu variable de session en todas las secciónes debes iniciar tu página con session_start(); en cada sección que requieras usarla.

Si pasas los parametros por GET estos se reflejarán en la URL.
Aun que si vas a leer la resolución de la pantalla no sería tan necesario hacerlo con PHP. Sino solo con JAVASCRIPT ej:

```
<div class="mensaje"></div>

<script>
var anchoVentana = $(window).width();
var altoVentana = $(window).height(); 
$(".mensaje").append(" Esta es tu resolucion de pantalla: ancho" + anchoVentana + " alto "+ altoVentana);
</script>
```

Comment: ah ok, pero como hago para analizar ese valor en javascript y asignar los padding-left y padding-right de codigo html ? me cuesta poder manejar la vinculacion entre javascript y html... me las rebusco con php y html

Comment: Todo tendrías que manejarlo con Javascript, es decir si quieres modificar los paddings en cuestión al ancho y alto puede ser por ejemplo: 

if(anchoVentana > 1024)
{
    $(".contenedor").css({'paddingLeft':'30px'});
    $(".contenedor").css({'paddingRight':'30px'});
}

Es solo jugar con las propiedades CSS con JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/css/